# Array Buttons Category Selection Like FLIPBOARD APP

Tags: android, list, arraylist, android-appcompat, android-button

I'm trying to do a filtering, in which the user selects his/her interest in the category section. Just like `FLIPBOARD` .

[image: Flipboard]

Mine:`simpleCategory.xml`

[image: Simple]

My sample crop code: `CategorySelection.java` basis [button Arrays sample](https://gist.github.com/zapl/2f94844ef4aef9df6a8206f06c474597)

```
private List<Button> buttons;
private static final int[] BUTTON_IDS = {
        R.id.buttonOne,
        R.id.buttonTwo,
        R.id.buttonThree,
        R.id.buttonFour,
        R.id.buttonFive,
        R.id.buttonSix,
        R.id.buttonSeven,
        R.id.buttonEight

};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.game_board_view);

    buttons = new ArrayList<Button>();

    for(int id : BUTTON_IDS) {
        Button button = (Button)findViewById(id);
        button.setOnClickListener(this); // maybe
        buttons.add(button);
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.buttonOne:
            Log.d("TAG", "Pressed button one.");
            break;
        case R.id.buttonTwo:
            Log.d("TAG", "Pressed button one.");
            break;
        // ...                
    }
```

1. How do I make the button Highlight if press.
2. Get the `Text` of the button position selected.
3. And Store them in a `temporaryVariable` those that are selected.

I need to get the data that is stored in `temporaryVariable` so that I can used in my `SQL Statement` like this

`$sql_filter = "SELECT orgName FROM orgData WHERE orgCategory = '$temporaryVariable'";`